# Creation of P2SH MultiSig Input Script

Tags: script, multi-signature, bitcoinj, p2sh

In the `createP2SHMultiSigInputScript()` function of BitcoinJ according to this:

public static Script createP2SHMultiSigInputScript(@NullableList signatures,**Script multisigProgram**)

*Create a program that satisfies a pay-to-script hashed OP_CHECKMULTISIG program. If given signature list is null, incomplete scriptSig will be created with OP_0 instead of signatures*

https://bitcoinj.github.io/javadoc/0.12/org/bitcoinj/script/ScriptBuilder.html#createP2SHMultiSigInputScript-java.util.List-org.bitcoinj.script.Script-

the **Script multisigProgam** input refers to the Redeem Script or the ScriptPubKey??

due to the fact that the `createP2SHMultiSigInputScript()` returns the ScriptSig script.

Comment: Downvoted because the question is not very clear and probably no longer useful today. I considered editing it to align it with my interpretation of what is being asked, but I'm not sure it's of much use today. Bitcoinj is not being used a lot anymore, and the asker probably solved the problem many years ago.—Happy to upvote if it's turned into a more useful question.